# Deriving electrostatics from Maxwell equations

Tags: vector-analysis, physics

When all electric charges are stationary (i.e. $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=0$ and $\mathbf{J}=0$), the Maxwell equations

$$\pmb{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}=\rho/\varepsilon_0,$$
$$\pmb{\nabla}\times\mathbf{E}=-\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t},$$
$$\pmb{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{B}=0,$$
$$\pmb{\nabla}\times\mathbf{B}=\mu_0\mathbf{J}+\varepsilon_0\mu_0\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t},$$
are directly reduced to

$$\pmb{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}=\rho/\varepsilon_0,$$
$$\pmb{\nabla}\times\mathbf{E}=-\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t},$$
$$\pmb{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{B}=0,$$
$$\pmb{\nabla}\times\mathbf{B}=\varepsilon_0\mu_0\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t},$$

where $\mu_0$ and $\varepsilon_0$ are physical constants. But from physics we know that when the charges are stationary, the Maxwell equations can be simplified further, to the following equations of electrostatics:

$$\pmb{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}=\rho/\varepsilon_0,$$
$$\pmb{\nabla}\times\mathbf{E}=0,$$
$$\pmb{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{B}=0,$$
$$\pmb{\nabla}\times\mathbf{B}=0.$$

Now the problem I'm thinking about is this: Let's forget all we known from physics, and consider everything from the perspective of pure mathematics. We have the first set of equations and we are given the conditions $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=0$ and $\mathbf{J}=0$. How can we derive the last set of equations?

Comment: We can't. And physics don't tell us that we can reduce the equations like you did just because charges are static. Electromagnetic waves can still exist in a vacuum free of charges or currents, and they require the first set of simplified equations. Electrostatics have $\dot E=\dot B=0$ as additional assumptions, though, and then simplifiying further is trivial.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos, here $J=0$ means $J(\mathbf{r},t)=0$, which means from the begining of time to the end of time all electric charges have been stationary. How can electromagnetic fields be produced in such world?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos, I should correct a mistake in my previous comment. I mean the charges have been stationary from the beginning of time. Shouldn't the Maxwell equations, themselves, show that E and B are not changing with time?

Comment: They could have been produced by changes in already existing fields. You probably like to assume the existence of charges from the beginning of time, so why not assume the existence of electromagnetic waves from the beginning of time? Nothing prevents that assumption. But then we wouldn't call that electrostatics. Essentially, you need some initial conditions for your fields, and those include the time derivatives of those fields. Electrostatics restrict your possible choice of initial conditions to $\dot E=\dot B=0$

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos, I do understand your point. But it's difficult to imagine a world in which no charge has ever moved, and yet there exists electromagnetic fields that change with time.